# Python Named Argument is Keyword?

Tags: python, keyword, named-parameters, reserved-words

So an optional parameter expected in the web POST request of an API I'm using is actually a reserved word in python too. So how do I name the param in my method call:

```
example.webrequest(x=1,y=1,z=1,from=1)
```

this fails with a syntax error due to 'from' being a keyword. How can I pass this in in such a way that no syntax error is encountered?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pass it as a dict.

```
func(**{'as': 'foo', 'from': 'bar'})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
args = {'x':1, 'y':1, 'z':1, 'from':1}
example.webrequest(**args)
```

// dont use that library

Comment: it's the Facebook Graph API ;)