# Reduce if statements to maximize efficiency in python

Tags: python, performance, if-statement, dictionary

I have write the following function to build parameters, i want to know that is there any other way in python to do that so that the code efficient is improved...

```
build_parameters(users[keys]["email"], Null , xsmtpapi, Message_Subject, Message_Content, Message_Content, 'support@brightspyre.com', 'BrightSpyre', 'support@brightspyre.com', Null, Null, Null, Null)
```

Here is the function

```
def build_parameters(to = None, toname = None, x-smtpapi = None, subject = None, text = None, html = None, from = None, cc = None, ccname = None, bcc = None, bccname = None, fromname = None, replyto = None, date = None, files = None, content = None, headers = None):
    param = {}
    if headers:
        param['headers'] = headers
    if content:
        param['content'] = content
    if files:
        param['files'] = files
    if date:
        param['date'] = date
    if replyto:
        param['replyto'] = replyto
    if fromname:
        param['fromname'] = fromname
    if bccname:
        param['bccname'] = bccname
    if bcc:
        param['bcc'] = bcc
    if ccname:
        param['ccname'] = ccname
    if cc:
        param['cc'] = cc
    if from:
        param['from'] = from
    if html:
        param['html'] = html
    if text:
        param['text'] = text
    if subject:
        param['subject'] = subject
    if x-smtpapi:
        param['x-smtpapi'] = x-smtpapi
    if toname:
        param['toname'] = toname
    if to:
        param['to'] = to

    return param
```

**UPDATED**

I have updated the code as described by `@J0HN`

```
_allowed_keys = {'to', 'toname', 'x-smtpapi', 'subject', 'text', 'html', 'from', 'cc', 'ccname', 'bcc', 'bccname', 'fromname', 'replyto', 'date', 'files', 'content', 'headers'}

def build_parameter(**kwargs):
    return {key:value for key, value in kwargs.items() if key in _allowed_keys}


params = build_parameter(to = users[keys]["email"], toname = users[keys]["name"], x-smtpapi = xsmtpapi, subject = Message_Subject,text = Message_Content, html = Message_Content, from = 'support@bs.com', fromname = 'BS', replyto = 'support@bs.com')
```

**error**

```
params = build_parameter(to = users[keys]["email"],toname = users[keys]["name"], x-smtpapi = xsmtpapi, subject = Message_Subject,text = Message_Content, html = Message_Content, from = '
support@bs.com', fromname = 'BSe', replyto = 'support@bs.com')                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                        ^    
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Cant' you just directly build a dictionary from where you are using it?

Comment: Just assign the values to the Keys without checking at all. You could also change the default value of the arguments to "".

Comment: No, actually its a function that check which arguments are passed and build the dictionary on arguments that are passed? some time all arguments are passed to function, something only 3 or 4 arguments. So i want to make it dynamic...

Comment: Then do as I said. Don't check and change default value to "". Empty strings won't harm when building the e-mail. If some of those parameters for example represent a list for cc in params['cc']: bla an empty string won't do any harm.

Comment: @ChristianRapp i had to build the api url using this param dictionary, if some value is empty then the url will be invalid... i have to make sure that only those keys are in the dictionary who has values.

Comment: The syntax error is because `from` is a keyword in Python. You can't use it as an identifier.

Comment: yes i know, but know that, but how would i avoid that because in the dictionary i am creating the from keyword is must.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
_allowed_keys = {'to', 'toname', 'x-smtpapi', ...]

def build_parameters(**kwargs):
    return {key:value for key, value in kwargs.items() if key in _allowed_keys}
```

Step by step:

- Define `_allowed_keys` to contain all keyword arguments' names. Refer to [set documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) for details.
- Replace parameters with `**kwargs`. Refer to [Understanding kwargs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python) for details on what's that.
- Use a [dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/python-create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension) to build a new dictionary out of `kwargs`
- `items` are used to iterate over key-value pair of a dictionary
- `key in _allowed_keys` is self-explanatory I believe

As a result, this function receives any number of keyword arguments, but filter out keys not in `_allowed_keys`.

**UPD**: ok, `from` is a keyword and `x-smtpapi` can't be a keyword argument as it contains `-`. It's an expected behavior, but the [canonical way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179175/python-named-argument-is-keyword) to workaround it renders the whole method useless.

So you'll need to represent them differently, e.g.:

```
_transforms = {'x_smtpapi'='x-smtpapi', `_from`='from'}

def build_parameter(**kwargs):
    return {_transforms.get(key, key):value for key, value in kwargs.items() if _transforms.get(key, key) in _allowed_keys}
```

And use like this `build_parameter(_from='from value', x_smtpapi: 'x-smtpapi value', ...)`

However, I wouldn't recommend doing this is it might be quite confusing. Instead, consider alternative approaches, e.g. build a class to encapsulate creating `params` dict (and probably using it)

Comment: then how would i call the function, is there need to specify the paramets name like`'build_parameters(to = 'taqi',...)` or needs to keep the order as definded in `allowed_keys`. I am beginner to python kindly help out. see teh question, i have updated.

Comment: @MuhammadTaqiHassanBukhari see that I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just build a dictionary.

```
params = {"to": "to value",
          "from": "from value}
```

There is no need to use a method for this.